# Make a table containing tokens visible for both .mly an .mll

Tags: parsing, ocaml, lexical-analysis, ocamllex, ocamlyacc

I would like to define a `keyword_table` which maps some strings to some tokens, and I would like to make this table visible for both `parser.mly` and `lexer.mll`.

It seems that the table has to be defined in `parser.mly`,

```
%{ 
  open Utility (* where hash_table is defined to make a table from a list *)
  let keyword_table = hash_table [
      "Call", CALL; "Case", CASE; "Close", CLOSE; "Const", CONST; 
      "Declare", DECLARE; "DefBool", DEFBOOL; "DefByte", DEFBYTE ]
%}
```

However, I could NOT use it in `lexer.mll`, for instance

```
{
open Parser
let x = keyword_table (* doesn't work *)
let x = Parser.keyword_table (* doesn't work *)
let x = Parsing.keyword_table (* doesn't work *)
}
```

Could anyone tell me where is the problem? Isn't it possible to make a data visible for both `parser.mly` and `lexer.mll`?

Comment: "doesn't work" is not helpful. What is the actual error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in [gsg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21519756/1633665), `ocamlyacc` generates a `mli` interface together with the `ml` implementation of the parser, and only exports the type of tokens and the entry points. According to http://caml.inria.fr/mantis/view.php?id=1703, this is unlikely to change, so you basically have two solutions:

- modify the generated `mli` afterwards (I usually have a rule in my `Makefile` that simply `rm` it, but you might want to just add the necessary signatures instead).
- use `menhir` as suggested in the bug report mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is fairly straightforward. You could simply place the data in a third .ml file and reference that:

In the .mly:

```
%{ 
    open Data
%}
```

In the .mll:

```
{
    open Data
}
```

You will not be able to refer to the internal definitions of `parse.mly` in other files. When `ocamlyacc` runs, it will generate a `parse.mli` that won't make them available.

Comment: except that the values in the hash table are most likely tokens that must be defined inside the `mly` file.