# Make a table containing tokens visible for both .mly and .mll by menhir

Tags: parsing, ocaml, lexical-analysis, ocamllex, menhir

I would like to define a `keyword_table` which maps some strings to some tokens, and I would like to make this table visible for both `parser.mly` and `lexer.mll`.

It seems that the table has to be defined in `parser.mly`,

```
%{ 
  open Utility (* where hash_table is defined to make a table from a list *)
  let keyword_table = hash_table [
      "Call", CALL; "Case", CASE; "Close", CLOSE; "Const", CONST; 
      "Declare", DECLARE; "DefBool", DEFBOOL; "DefByte", DEFBYTE ]
%}
```

However, I could NOT use it in `lexer.mll`, for instance

```
{
open Parser
let x = keyword_table (* doesn't work *)
let x = Parser.keyword_table (* doesn't work *)
let x = Parsing.keyword_table (* doesn't work *)
}
```

As [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21529379/702977) suggests, `menhir` has a solution for this, could anyone tell me any details?

Answer (score 3):

The first option is to define tokens in a separate `.mly` file. Executing `menhir` for this file with `--only-tokens` option will generate a module containing `type token` that you can use in your parser compiled with `--external-tokens` option.

If this solves the problem with tokens, you can specify all other functions that are used by both parser and lexer in a separate file as Thomash suggested.

There is an alternative solution as well. You can use `%parameter<module signature>` declaration in the parser to parametrize the entire parser over type and function annotations specified inside given signature. The main advantage is that this signature is provided in the interface file for the parser, so the parser can share this signature with other modules (that can construct modules based on the signature).

I suggest to refer [to `menhir` examples](https://github.com/pippijn/menhir/tree/master/demos), namely see `calc-two` to get know about external tokens and to `calc-param` to know how to create parametrized parsers.

Answer (score 0):

I usually put the `keyword_table`in `lexer.mll` and I see no reason to put it in `parser.mly`.
If you need to access it from both `lexer.mll` and `parser.mly` (but why do you want to access it from parser.mly?), the easiest solution is to put it in a third file `keyword.ml` and use `Keyword.keyword_table` (or `open Keyword` and `keyword_table`).

Comment: The problem is that the `keyword_table` contains tokens, I can't put it in a third file `keyword.ml`...

Comment: This is not a problem, see the doc for `--external-tokens`

Comment: I [have used](http://www.ii.uni.wroc.pl/~lukstafi/pmwiki/uploads/Functional/functional-lecture09.pdf) `--external-tokens` because of some problems I have had with `ocamlbuild`. It gives more flexibility anyway.